# How to configure MQTT mosquitto with TPM engine

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, tpm

I have configured MQTT Mosquitto and enabled SSL and i have connected securely using certificates **cafile**, **certfile** and **keyfile** tested using **MQTT.FX** client.

The problem is , is there any way to enable TPM engine which can store certificates in it and connect to MQTT client.

I have refered this link [image]
https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an OpenSSL capability that Mosquitto is just exposing some of the config for.

Have a look at something like [this](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss-engine) which is a plugin to add TPM2.0 support

Comment: Thank you so much hardillb. I have configured as per the given link page and installed whatever required libraries, but when I create certificate openssl  using tpm2tss key(rsa .tss) I am getting initialization tcti error and if I run sudo openssl... command getting Received TPM error.

Comment: Sorry, you will have to raise that with the tpm2-tss-engine project.

Answer (score 0):

By default MQTT clients are not support to bridge via TPM engine.
What you can do use proxy in local via other help of other container.

`MQTT client (local machine) connect to` -> `NGINX (alpine) container` -> TCP Proxy to `remote MQTT server`.
I assume you have all necessary parameters are exist on `x509` certificate.
You can refer one of my article and change it accordingly.

https://medium.com/@farizmuradov/making-tpm2-0-chip-usage-easy-for-all-applications-in-iot-4c34775ff12